# Add a default style if no Featured image is selected

Tags: php, css, post-thumbnails

How do I have a fallback CSS style if no featured image is selected in WordPress? I'd rather remove the featured image block and replace with some CSS class if nothing is selected.

```
<?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( 
get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );?>
<div id="post" class="featured-image" style="background-image: url('<? 
php echo $thumb['0'];?>')">
```

[Added Featured Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWHB0.jpg)

[image: Default CSS - No Featured Image Selected]

Answer (score 0):

You can test if the `$thumb` has any contents and then apply a class to the featured image block that you can use to hide the container.

```
<?php
    $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src(
        get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID),
        'full'
    );
?>

<div id="post" class="featured-image <?php echo empty($thumb) ? 'no-featured-image-class' : ''; ?>" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $thumb['0']; ?>')">
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! How do I insert the alternate CSS class? 

Say I want to use ( .featured-image-2 )

Comment: This section of the code `class="featured-image <?php echo empty($thumb) ? 'no-featured-image-class' : ''; ?>"` is where the extra css class is added.  `no-featured-image-class` being the class name.  You should replace that with the class name you would like to use, `featured-image-2`.  Alternatively, you could edit the statement to use either one or the other class name.  That would look like this: `class="<?php echo empty($thumb) ? 'no-featured-image-class' : 'featured-image'; ?>`.